# How do I call the Google Cardboard QR scanner wizard in a Unity script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I would like to call the Google Cardboard QR scanner wizard using a script in a scene that does't have stereo view. Is there way to do it? Thanks!

For scanner wizard I mean the screen that pops up after launch and request access to the camera to scan the QR code of the cardboard.